# searching/showing size of files

Tags: linux, bash, files, disk-usage

is there an easy way to look through a directory and say, for every file that starts with a-z, print the total size of those files?

for example

```
for i in {97..122}; du (something); done
```

i.e output>>

a- 123kb

b- 22kb

...

z- 1245kb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved via globbing

```
$ du [a-z]*
456 asdf.png
12  awk.trace
28  blink_image_resources_200_percent.pak
0   Books
```

Note that if an item expanded by the glob is a directory, `du` will traverse that directory's contents, so if you are only concerned with directory's total size and not individual listing of items, you might want to do `du -s [a-z]*`. If you want human-readable suffix such as `k` or `M`, use `-h` option.

Of course, shells like `bash` and `ksh` have more fine-grained pattern matching,  `bash` has `extglob` shell option and `globstar` for recursive traversal to match filenames. `find` command can also be used for recursive and fine-grained filename matching, even excluding directories as in

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec du -s {} \;
```

---

It's also worth noting, that brace expansion such as `{0..9}` doesn't perform pathname expansion, that is `*` expands to what already exists in the directory, `{0..9}` expands to list of tokens which may or may not exist in the current working directory.